# Java error when trying to run Selenium Standalone

Tags: java, selenium

1. I installed Java 6 on Windows 7
2. I copied a file called `selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar` in the `c:\Selenium` directory
3. Open the command prompt and browse to the `c:\Selenium` directory
4. Run the following command in (without quotes).

> Java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar

An Error is returned:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ujar, etc...

I checked system variables, and are the following:

```
CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH = c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin  (this was missing so I added it)
QTJAVA = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
```

Any help resolving this error is appreciated.

Comment: This could be some kind of problem with the test suit file. Could you add it (at least, a significant fragment of it) to your question?

Comment: Can you add the whole exception message to your question? The "etc..." part is probably going to contain useful information.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and could solve it by **manually retyping the`-jar`part** in command line.
In my case I copied the command line from a word document. And it seems that the `-` of word had a different character code than command prompt's `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar` to the classpath

Comment: Running with the -jar option automatically adds it to the classpath.

Comment: @CameronSkinner can you please provide a quote/reference/link for your comment?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#-jar states that "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored." So I guess it would have been more correct for me to say "running with the -jar option means the named jar, and only that jar, will be on the classpath". In any case, the point is that it's already on the classpath.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ûj
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ûjar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: ΓÇôjar.  Program will exit.

Answer (score -1):

Your classpath is wrong. It is pointing to QTJAVA.zip file. Remove the classpath variable and run the jar again.

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong, the QTJava.zip may be a perfectly valid dependency for some other program, and should not be removed

Comment: My class path is now: .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar